# Div just drags up when trying to scroll on mobile?

Tags: html, ios, twitter-bootstrap

As the title says my div is getting dragged along with the finger when trying to scroll past it on the phone :/ so the background color behind it is showing.

How do I disable that?

It's not the whole div, mostly the iframe or the div the iframe is in.
But in other divs I have cards that do the same.

What causes it?

Code of one div:

```
<div class="Contact" id="Contact">
    <div class="normalOverlay">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="text-center footertext">Kontakt information</h1>
            <hr>
            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 40px">
                <div class="mapouter"><div class="gmap_canvas"><iframe width="100%" 
                                                                   height="400" 
                                                                   id="gmap_canvas" 
                                                                   src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=h%C3%B6vdingagatan%2039&t=&z=15&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" 
                                                                   frameborder="0" 
                                                                   scrolling="no"
                                                                   marginheight="0" 
                                                                   marginwidth="0">
                  </iframe><a href="https://www.crocothemes.net">crocothemes.net</a></div>
            <style>
                .mapouter {
                    text-align: right;
                    height: 400px;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .gmap_canvas {
                    overflow: hidden;
                    background: none !important;
                    height: 400px;
                    width: 100%;
                }
            </style></div>
            @*<iframe src="https://maps.google.com/maps?width=100%&amp;height=600&amp;hl=en&amp;q=H%C3%B6vdingagatan%2039%2C%20126%2052%20H%C3%A4gersten%2C%20Sverige+(Bil2000)&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=B&amp;output=embed" " width="100%" height="320" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>*@
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box1 pt-4">
                <a href="tel:">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone fa-3x"></i>
                    <h3 class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">Telefon</h3>
                    <p class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block"></p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box2 pt-4">
                <a href="">
                    <i class="fas fa-home fa-3x"></i>
                    <h3 class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">Adress</h3>
                    <p class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">

                    </p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 box3 pt-4">
                <a href="mailto:">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-3x"></i>
                    <h3 class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">E-mail</h3>
                    <p class="d-none d-lg-block d-xl-block">

                    </p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <h5>Öppettider:</h5>
            <p class="footertext">
                Mån-tor 09.00-17.00
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Contact {
background-color: #003333;
position: relative;
height: 100vh;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: post the relevant coding

Answer (score 0):

You didnt closed the div tag somewhere, the tag isnt closed so the container doesnt ends.

Comment: No it does, the formating was just wierd after pasting, will fix it :)

Comment: Look at my answer again

Comment: Yeah but it does close, atleast in my code, just checked it.